# Trying to write and read via serial to a GPS module on Raspberry Pi 3b+ without any success

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to write commands to and read from a SIM808 GPS module using a Raspberry Pi 3B+. The AT command to turn on the module is `AT+CGPSPWR=1`. This is my python code (I'm a complete python noob),

```
from time import sleep
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0', #Replace ttyS0 with ttyAM0 for Pi1,Pi2,Pi0
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=2.0
)

print(ser.name) # check which port was really used
ser.write(b'AT+CGPSPWR=1'+'\r\n') #turn on the GPS module
sleep(2)
ser.write(b'AT+CGPSOUT=2'+'\r\n') #set the module to output GGA sentence every 1 second
state = ser.readline()
print (state)
```

With this, I get the following error,

```
/dev/ttyS0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps-sim808-test.py", line 14, in <module>
    ser.write(b'AT+CGPSPWR=1'+'\r\n') #turn on the GPS module
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

After a little time on SO, I tried this,

`ser.write(('AT+CGPSPWR=1'+'\r\n').encode) #turn on the GPS module` and got this error,

```
/dev/ttyS0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps-sim808-test.py", line 14, in <module>
    ser.write(('AT+CGPSPWR=1'+'\r\n').encode) #turn on the GPS module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 532, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 66, in to_bytes
    return bytes(bytearray(seq))
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to convert the string to bytes. This is how I did it and this works,

```
ser.write(bytes("AT+CGPSPWR=1\n", 'utf-8')) #turn on the GPS module
rx = ser.readline()
print (rx.decode('utf-8'))
```